# Can we authenticate using gmail email-id and password instead of serviceaccount programmatically to access compute engine instances ?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I am writing a python utility to access the compute engine instances across the projects a user has access to. Can we achieve this by authenticating to google cloud platform projects and instances using gmail email and password ?

My utility program will be used by multiple users and I cannot store serviceaccount of each user for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want end user authentication.

Endpoints supports this:
https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/authenticating-users

For reference, here is a doc on choosing a type of authentication method:
https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/authentication-method